# Drawing A Square in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on an Android OpenGL ES tutorial and it says: "defining triangles is pretty easy in OpenGL, but what if you want to get a just a little more complex? Say, a square? There are a number of ways to do this, but a typical path to drawing such a shape in OpenGL ES is to use two triangles drawn together"

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/shapes.html

[image]

Why is the typical path to drawing such a shape to use two triangles instead of drawing the four corner coordinates of the square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphics cards and rendering options are only really coded to render triangles, and not anything harder. The idea is that every other shape anyone could ever think of can be duplicated or approximated with triangles, sometimes billions or trillions of them. When you see GPUs being compared, sometimes you hear "maximum polygons on the screen" or something similar. They really mean triangles, but polygons sounds cooler. Triangles are simple enough to create, but provide fantastic utility. They don't need to have ordered points, which is a huuuge help.

The tl;dr answer is that GPUs render triangles really well, so much so they don't bother knowing how to render much else.

Comment: Another big advantage of triangles is that they are always planar. Other polygons can potentially be non-planar, which makes their rasterization ambiguous.